# The newly added data to my Access database doesn't work in the queries

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

So this Monday, I tried to run the following query and it worked:

```
SELECT 
    DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
FROM 
    Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
WHERE 
   p.DiagnoseID = d.ID 
   AND med.PatientID = p.ID 
   AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID 
   AND p.ID = " + lbPatientsID.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

In this, the `lbPatientsId.SelectedItem.ToString()` is a variable from my program. Now if I open my Access database and add a new row of data to the table "Patient" and I try to run that query, it doesn't work. However, when I run the query with the ID of an old patient it does work.

This works (`p.ID` (Patient ID) created before today):

```
SELECT 
    DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
FROM 
    Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
WHERE 
    p.DiagnoseID = d.ID 
    AND med.PatientID = p.ID 
    AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID 
    AND p.ID = 21;
```

This doesn't work (`p.ID` (Patient ID) created today):

```
SELECT 
    DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
FROM 
    Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
WHERE 
    p.DiagnoseID = d.ID 
    AND med.PatientID = p.ID 
    AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID 
    AND p.ID = 31;
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @RedFilter It means that I get no data from the query and my database is filled with data.

Comment: Remove that `WHERE` condition and see if the record is there at all.  If the data isn't found then it's not there, Access isn't lying to you about that.

Comment: @David Yup, I get all the data when I remove the `WHERE` condition.

Comment: @Merikw: If the row(s) you want is/are there, but the query doesn't find it/them, then your `WHERE` condition is incorrect.  You're going to have to debug it, we can't possibly tell you what might be wrong given the information provided.

Comment: Please share with us how are the tables related (diagram or creation scripts) otherwise is very hard to help you further. Check related tables to see what is the difference between patient 21 and 31 (some fields might be null or incorrectly linked or someone else altered data for patient 31 for tests

Comment: I'd guess that one or more of your tables does not have 31 in it. Because of the nature of your query using where instead of joins, this could result in zero rows. Consider rewriting your query to use left joins to test for nulls from a single master table you KNOW 31 is in.

Answer (score 0):

So since you quote

```
lbPatientsID.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

, it would pass as "lbPatientsID.SelectedItem.ToString()".

So if you want make it work as

```
P.ID = "{Some selected value}"
```

do like this:

```
SELECT DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
FROM  Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
WHERE p.DiagnoseID = d.ID 
AND med.PatientID = p.ID 
AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID 
AND p.ID = " "+ lbPatientsID.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Then I think it would WORK as what you want.

Comment: Still doesn't work for the data that I inserted today into the database. When I debug it in Visual Studio it tells me that `while (reader.Read())` HasRows = false. However, when I insert data which I put into the database before monday, than HasRows = true in the same piece of code.

Comment: @Merikw let's try this way. Could you change equal to like, and see if you could get any result

Comment: no, still only the data that I put in the database before this monday. The data from today is nog showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Since p.ID is being compared to 31 I guess this should work (should show you data)

```
SELECT DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
    FROM Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
    WHERE p.DiagnoseID = d.ID AND med.PatientID = 31
        AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID AND p.ID = 31;
```

Or also trying making your where less restrictive

```
WHERE 
    p.DiagnoseID = d.ID AND med.PatientID = 31
--  AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID AND p.ID = 31; 

WHERE 
--  p.DiagnoseID = d.ID AND med.PatientID = 31
--  AND 
    med.MedicijnID = m.ID AND p.ID = 31;
```

Also try removeing the WHERE an use TOP to avoid overloading the DataBase

```
SELECT TOP 10 DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
    FROM Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
    WHERE p.DiagnoseID = d.ID AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID
```

Comment: I just tried all of your possibilities, however non of them worked.
         `SELECT DatumOntslag, p.Naam, d.Naam, med.ID, m.Naam, HoeVaakPerDag 
    FROM Patient p, Diagnose d, Medicatie med, Medicijn m 
    WHERE p.DiagnoseID = d.ID AND med.PatientID = 31
        AND med.MedicijnID = m.ID AND p.ID = 31;  this doesn't give any data.` 

However, when I change `p.ID` into for example 21 instead is 31, another patient in my database, it gives me all the data that I need.

Comment: Please share with us how are the tables related (diagram or creation scripts) otherwise is very hard to help you further. Check related tables to see what is the difference between patient 21 and 31 (some fields might be null or incorrectly linked or someone else altered or is using that patient 31 for tests